# Injecting beans in a JUnit/Mockito test returns zero

Tags: java, junit, mockito, ejb

I have a JavaEE application with Stateless EJBs that I use for business logic (`EjbBusiness`) and database access (`EjbDAO`). I need to run a unit test on `EjbBusiness`, but the DAO method always returns zero.

In the example below I have both classes and the unit test. I mock the `EjbDAO` method that connects to the database, to return a testing SQL connection:

```
@Stateless
public class EjbDAO {


    public Connection getConnFromPool() {
        Connection conn = null; // in production this would return a connection
        return conn;
    }


    public int add2(int i) {
        Connection conn = getConnFromPool();
        System.out.println("in EjbDAO: " + i);
        return i + 2;
    }

}


@Stateless
public class EjbBusiness {


    @Inject
    private EjbDAO dao;


    public int add2(int i) {
         int j = dao.add2(i);
         System.out.println("in EjbBusiness: " + j);
         return j;

    }

}
```

Since I mock one of the methods of EjbDAO, I annotate it with @Spy in `UnitTest`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UnitTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private EjbBusiness biz;

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private EjbDAO dao;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        dao = Mockito.mock(EjbDAO.class);
        biz = Mockito.mock(EjbBusiness.class);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testBean() {

        // this would return the testing connection
        Mockito.doReturn(null).when(dao).getConnFromPool();

        int i = biz.add2(3);

        assertThat(5).isEqualTo(i);
    }
}
```

Problem is that the assertion doesn't work, as `biz.add2(3)` returns zero instead of 5. Also, the `System.out.println` in both beans is not printed. How to declare/mock the beans for the test to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@InjectMocks` only when you calling actual method otherwise don't use it. And also don't use `@InjectMocks` and `Mockito.mock() or @Mock` together.

In your code you are using `@InjectMocks` on `dao` object and you are also creatign mock for that. And use `Mockito.mock()` when you want to stub the method calls instead of calling actual methods.

`System.out.println()` is not working in your code because you created mocks for objects `biz` and `dao`. Actual methods (i.e `add2()` because of this you are getting `0` as output) not executed when you call with mock objects.

For more info on when to use `@InjectMocks` refer 
[this](https://howtodoinjava.com/mockito/mockito-mock-injectmocks/)

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UnitTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private EjbBusiness biz;

    @Mock
    private EjbDAO dao;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testBean() {

        // this would return the testing connection
        Mockito.doReturn(null).when(dao).getConnFromPool();
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(dao).add2(Mockito.anyInt());

        int i = biz.add2(3);

        assertThat(i).isEqualTo(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, however the problem with this approach is that if I have in the dao object only one method to mock out and 10 where I need to run the real method, I need to declare for each real method `Mockito.doCallRealMethod()` . Is there a way to do the opposite? For example to declare the entire class and only one method to mock.

Comment: @ps0604 can you give an example

Answer (score 1):

You should not use one unit test to test both classes. 
You should have two test classes to test them.

For Example,

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EjbBusinessTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private EjbBusiness biz;

    @Mock
    private EjbDAO dao;


    @Test
    public void testAdd2() {

        // this would return the testing connection
        Mockito.doReturn(null).when(dao).getConnFromPool();
        Mockito.doReturn(5).when(dao).add2();

        int i = biz.add2(3);

        assertThat(5).isEqualTo(i);
    }
}
```

In the above class we are testing only the method `EjbBusinessTest.add2` and we don't care what happens or if the method `EjbDAO.add2` is working properly. In this all we should care is whether the method under test is working properly, hence we mock everything external to that method.

Following a similar approach for `EjbDAO.add2` as well, The test case should look like something given below. I have also made the method `EjbDAO.getConnection` private so that that should also be included in the test. This choice should be made by you if you need to make it private or public. If you decide to keep it public then you should use @Spy on `EjbDAO` and mock the `EjbDAO.getConnection` method.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EjbDAOTest {

    //instantiate this object the way you want. Mock the external objects used inside this like the library used to get connection inside EjbDAO.getConnection() Method  
    @InjectMocks
    private EjbDAO dao;


    @Test
    public void testAdd2() {

        // I would suggest you to make the getConnection method private.
        // do not mock the getConnection here, instead mock how you are getting the connection inside the  getConnection method. 
        int i = dao.add2(3);

        assertThat(5).isEqualTo(i);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.